# Including a PHP file inside a jQuery statement within a Smarty template

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I want to include a file if the condition is applied in jQuery using Smarty templates
my Code :

```
{literal}
<script>
      if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    // here is the include file
    {include= file.tpl}
        }
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: I'm thinking in two ways for doing that: A. Include your file inside a hidden div, and show it when condition is matched. B. If condition is matched, do an Ajax request, receive the content you want, and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have good news and bad news. First, the bad news: This code as it is will never work, because your Smarty template has been already evaluated on the server in order to generate HTML and send it out to the browser and your Javascript code will only be evaluated once the request has responded to the browser. So, the `{include= file.tpl}` will be generated into your HTML, specifically into your `script` tag, yielding unwanted results.

The good news is that the issue is solvable. The solution can be to

## Generate your literal HTML and hide it by default

In which case you can change the `display` CSS attribute of your literal template(s) if the condition is met.

## Or, you can just POST for the literal when you need it

If the JS condition is true, then you can send an AJAX post to the server which would answer with the template.

## Finally, you can use media queries

If this is **only** about styling, then you can use [media queries][1].

You can also use the `media` attribute of your `link` tag to load the right stylesheet.
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{literal}
<script>
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
 {/literal}{include= file.tpl}{literal}
}
</script>
{/literal}
```